# How do I assign this code to show only on specific categories?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

On our products pages we have a Wallpapers category.  For each product in that category we want to show this code.

We can make it show on all products, and this code was written to exclude categories, but we want to to show only for set categories.

We are using a Permalink Wordprss plugin to remove /product/ or /product-category/ from the URLs.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'content_after_addtocart_button' );
function content_after_addtocart_button() {
echo '<div style="clear: both; margin-bottom: 30px"></div>
<div class="product-buttons">
<a href="/wallpaper-samples/">Order Sample</a></div>';
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query' , 'exclude_cat_shortcodes');

function exclude_cat_shortcodes($query_args){

    $query_args['tax_query'] =  array(array( 
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 
            'field' => 'slug', 
            'terms' => array('wallpaper'), // Don't display products from this category
            'operator' => 'AND'
        )); 

    return $query_args;
}
```

This should work, but it doesn't.

```
'add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'content_after_addtocart_button' );
function content_after_addtocart_button() {
echo '<div style="clear: both; margin-bottom: 30px"></div>
<div class="product-buttons">
<a href="/wallpaper-samples/">Order Sample</a></div>';
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query' , 'exclude_cat_shortcodes');

function exclude_cat_shortcodes($query_args){

    $query_args['tax_query'] =  array(array( 
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 
            'field' => 'slug', 
            'terms' => array('wallpaper'), // Don't display products from this category
            'operator' => 'AND'
        )); 

    return $query_args;
}'
```

To show a Order Samples button on screen, only for the Wallpaper product category.

Answer (score 1):

Add this.
this will work 100%.
Add this parameter --> `'terms'    => $categories_id`

```
array(
      'taxonomy' => 'our_project_category',
      'field'    => 'term_id',
      'terms'    => $categories_id,
    )
```